# Output age on Birthday with Calendar \usepackage{montly}

Tags: calculations

I want to display the age of multiple people on my calendar. I can get the current year to come through with `\the\year`, but I can't figure out how to solve an equation in the option below (part of `birthdays.cld`)

```
 every 25 August {Mr. Kale's Birthday! \solvethismathproblem{\the\year - 1983 years old}}
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no `montly` (or `monthly`?) package

Comment: Part of this: http://ctan.org/pkg/calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

`\the\numexpr\year-1983` will calculate the difference between the current year (as long as the `\year` register has not been screwed up) and the year `1983` and print the result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\yearofbirth{1983}
\begin{document}

Foo is \the\numexpr\year-\yearofbirth\ year(s) old
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a more convenient approach with a macro and a way without using `\numexpr` (which is an `e-TeX` invention)

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{agecntr}

\newcommand{\printage}[2][\year]{%
  \the\numexpr#1-#2%
}

\newcommand{\printageother}[2][\year]{%
  \setcounter{agecntr}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{agecntr}{-#2}%
  \theagecntr%
}
\def\yearofbirth{1983}
\begin{document}

Foo is \the\numexpr\year-\yearofbirth\ year(s) old

Foo is \printage{1980}\ year(s) old

Foo is \printageother{1974}\ year(s) old
\end{document}
```